# jQuery - How to search within a class for a partial match and remove that class only?

Tags: jquery, class, tablerow

Well, I am storing variables inside of a class that will be used for other elements.  Might not be the best approach for this, but is easier to do when I grab the element using `$("tr").each(function{ // code });`  Perhaps there is a better attribute to store these variables in??  Or a better overall way of doing it?

But basically, I am trying to use the `markRow:` text as a beginning string to the variable that I need to determine if this `tr` element has within it's class.  If it has the text "markRow:", I than need to `split(":")`, only this class (because the `tr` elements can have more than 1 class defined on them), into an array and only grab the 2nd array bound.  Than, after I use these variables, I need to wipe out all classes from each `tr` element that has `markRow:` defined within the class, but don't want to remove any other classes that these `tr` elements might have within them when doing this.

Can someone please get me started on this?  Was thinking of the selector `:contains` for a partial match for the `markRow:` string, but not sure if this is any good.  Perhaps using `filter` somehow might help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding of your problem here is what you can try.

```
$('tr').each(function(){
   var $tr = $(this), classes = $tr[0].className, finalClasses = [];

   //If className contains 'markRow:' then process it
   if(classes.indexOf('markRow:') != -1){
       $.each(classes.split(' '), function(i, class){
          //If class does not contain `markRow:' 
          //then add this class else ignore it
          if(class.indexOf('markRow:') == -1){
             finalClasses.push(class);
          }
       }); 
       //Finally combine all the classes not containing `markRow:` 
       //and set it to tr
       $tr[0].className = finalClasses.join(' ');
   }
});
```

Keeping your problem aside I would suggest you to use data attributes to pass on data along with element on the page. It becomes very easy to retrieve data from data attributes.

E.g.

```
<div data-info="someInfo" id="div1"></div>
```

To get `data-info` attribute value from `div1` element you can use the below code.

```
var info = $('#div1').data('info');
```

To set `data-info` you can use this code

```
$('#div1').data('info', 'someInfo');
```

`.data()` reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Comment: Ok, great will try the `data()` method than.  Awesome, didn't know about this.  Just wondering if it's XML compliant though?

Comment: For understanding data attributes take a look at this link http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Comment: It says this:  `Note: this method currently does not provide cross-platform support for setting data on XML documents, as Internet Explorer does not allow data to be attached via expando properties.`  I don't think I'm setting data on an XML document here, since it's directly on the element, but Need it to be cross-browser compatible BTW...

Comment: Yes, data attributes on html elements are supported across all browsers. If the browser do not support them natively, `jQuery` adds its own code to handle it. So don't worry about cross browser support for using data attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you want to do, you might want to try using the `data()` method from jQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

That is set up to do what you're trying to accomplish, only properly.